# Error in plotting line graph, bar graph plots without error

Tags: python, pandas, plot

I have a dataframe with one column of type datetime and other floats. when I am plotting the dataframe while specifying kind='bar', I get the plot. But if I do not specify bar( i.e. I want line graph) I get an error

My dataframe:

```
    DATE         Act         fig1            Fig2           Fig3
0   2019-01-27  46027.37998 58285.4684  41219.228434982215  45064.25892364141
1   2019-01-28  55069.98999 57206.1157  48344.78846433562   48890.21159327326
2   2019-01-29  49297.31    56990.239   48088.530894421005  46813.0926774736
3   2019-01-30  53094.96997 58285.4684  52657.76140749706   51054.21267889635
4   2019-01-31  68815.61003 66488.6087  61910.84509456238   58310.31961711759
5   2019-02-01  82316.24003 71397.8652  75604.92380324422   81543.81974813671
6   2019-02-02  66563.15001 63090.4584  67020.6870408009    71332.9316668577
7   2019-02-03  39375.72    47914.6791  35901.756450152665  46120.40005916364
8   2019-02-04  41562.65001 52081.1774  43750.363854695555  47366.99449131916
9   2019-02-05  39364.66001 56247.6654  39848.36712727402   46162.050789218716
10  2019-02-06  44340.77    60414.1637  44113.74894783513   40196.60401064496
11  2019-02-07  54721.35002 66663.9009  49005.105053347426  55410.79149194656
12  2019-02-08  59968.76002 69580.4517  56733.77675923111   72458.28140044466
13  2019-02-09  53178.19001 63747.3603  42389.23467005711   64498.91389851934
14  2019-02-10  30877.04998 43593.2373  28313.94468739357   38429.596789119816
15  2019-02-11  34470.58003 44290.7238  35604.17450889417   45831.545410152874
16  2019-02-12  39826.35997 45336.9689  35920.76086080937   45535.88297224278
17  2019-02-13  42989.98009 47778.1869  38911.1770698405    48524.29063181302
18  2019-02-14  49793.46996 54055.6164  45399.86041447529   55548.64846121237
19  2019-02-15  47080.76999 61030.5323  59848.07905886687   67752.30460448604
20  2019-02-16  47249.78008 52660.6332  54688.47435532434   62532.07407812223
21  2019-02-17  26331.26005 43561.6887  30852.52110020275   40166.70663955889
22  2019-02-18  25287.14    47433.8385  34835.54664477423   43847.75648201314
23  2019-02-19  32967.26997 51305.9884  34425.44824792564   42824.853554862006
24  2019-02-20  30504.48001 55178.1383  34378.403143393065  42577.48304603604
25  2019-02-21  44767.48002 61179.968   43722.93426281729   52739.538652256015
26  2019-02-22  44889.52998 67762.6177  58421.63331088934   67469.02284121823
27  2019-02-23  51204.47002 60792.7479  53582.06434917556   61629.110622570355
```

dff.info() as below

```
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
Int64Index: 28 entries, 0 to 27
Data columns (total 5 columns):
DATE      28 non-null datetime64[ns]
Act       28 non-null float64
fig1      28 non-null float64
Fig2      28 non-null float64
Fig3      28 non-null float64
dtypes: datetime64[ns](1), float64(4)
memory usage: 1.3 KB
```

Following line plots correclty

```
dff.set_index('DATE').plot(kind='bar')
```

Following line gives error - float() argument must be a string or a number, not 'Period'

```
dff.set_index('DATE').plot()
```

I am not sure but I remember plotting dataframes with datetime type in one column without problem. Is it an issue with new version of Pandas. what can I do? My Pandas version is 0.24.2.

Thanks.

Comment: I am not able to duplicate any errors with 'dff.set_index('DATE').plot()'.  I got the expected line graph.   What error message?  I am using pandas 0.24.2.

Comment: Same for me. I could not reproduce your error. I get the expected graph. My pandas version is 0.24.2 aswell

Comment: @ scott- I have mentioned the error above, here it is- float() argument must be a string or a number, not 'Period'. I get blank plot and the error.

Comment: Can you add dff.info() or df.to_dict() outputs to this question?

Comment: @scott- added the required info. when you replicate please make sure to create 'DATE' as datetime as type Object plots without problem as I checked. TIA

Comment: @arb.... I am not able to generate any error.

Comment: I'm too, unable to replicate your error, neither with `DATE` as `string` nor `datetime` in pandas 0.24.2 and matplotlib 3.0.3.

Comment: @ Scott/ Quang- thats weird , I am getting same error in v 0.24.2 but worked in v 0.23 in other machine. Can different version of matplotlib be an issue or is it just Pandas. I am working on 2.2.3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a bug in pandas, downgrading to pandas `0.20.2` will fix it. You can do so by:

`pip install 'pandas==0.22.0'`

Comment: Can you point to documentation of this bug?  I was not able to duplicate with pandas '0.24.2'.

Comment: @ScottBoston, is your index of datetimeindex type? The bug appears when you have dadatetimeindex type index and not when you have strings (type 'O'). This is being discussed here: https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/14763

Comment: When I copied the same dataframe, column 'DATE' changed to type datetime and I could plot line graph. This explains why no error could not be replicated. Looks like problem occurs in datetimeindex as Pankaj mentioned.